# Javascript Twitter not working on one Host but works on another

Tags: javascript, plugins, twitter

I'm currently working on a website which requires a twitter plugin so I used the plugin creator on the twitter website to create a plugin and simply copy an pasted the code into a page.

It works fine when I upload the page and plugin to my own webspace however it doesn't when I upload it to the clients webspace.

Please take a look:

http://www.biguppower.com/test.html

http://s438332955.websitehome.co.uk/test.html

Has anyone got any ideas on why this could be.

Thanks, Sami.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look to the console and this is written :

> You have not whitelisted this domain for your Twitter widget. Go to
>   https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/260161750970793984/edit and add
>   'www.biguppower.com' to the 'Domains' list for this timeline.

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks guys, makes sense now, won't let me accept the answer for 11 minutes so will do then.